# Vapor crashes when uses MongoSwift on ubuntu

Tags: swift, mongodb, ubuntu, vapor

Im trying to create a vapor API to my app. On my local machine ( Mac OS ) All my code and my API works perfectly but when i upload it to my ubuntu server it crashes...

I already did the following code:

`vapor clean`
`vapor update`
`vapor build`

None of these commands return any type of errors but when i run vapor the following happens:

`root@rt-server:/usr/local/uprising/server# vapor run
Running server ...
root@rt-server:/usr/local/uprising/server#`

Searching a bit and making some trys to fix my problem i figgured out that if i comment the following code ( configure.swift ), i can make vapor runs:

```
//     Register Mongo Client
let client = try! MongoClient()
let db = client.db("myDB")
let collection:MongoCollection<Document>
do {
    collection = try db.createCollection("myCollection")
} catch {
    collection = db.collection("myCollection")
}
// Create an unique index on timestamp
// because I expect only one daily
let indexOptions = IndexOptions(name: "timestamp", unique: true)
let model = IndexModel(keys: [ "timestamp": 1] , options: indexOptions)
do {
    try collection.createIndex(model)
} catch {
    print("Index already exist!")
}
services.register(client)
```

I have some questions that maybe help me figgure out how solve my problem:

- How do i debug vapor using command line on ubuntu? In my mac its easy when i use xcode...
- Can i test if my MongoDB C Driver is properly installed?
- Does anyone knows what am i doing wrong? it works perfectly on my mac...

Sorry for my bad engish... If anyone knows how to help me i would appreciate that!

Comment: Debugging: [swift-lldb](https://github.com/apple/swift-lldb) ... note the build status per various platforms.

Answer (score 1):

swift MacOS runtime environment != swift Linux runtime environment. It means, the code that build and works perfect in MacOS not very often compiles in Linux. I implemented several Linux swift projects and my suggestion is: develop Linux swift project in Linux from the beginning of the project!
For your case:

1) In most cases Linux swift project run in production using docker.

2) Get Linux host with the same environment as in docker container

3) Migrate your project to Linux host

4) In Linux host you can build, execute and debug it.

Also, for one of my Linux Swift project when I need to access to MongoDB, I tested several frameworks and [MongoKitten](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten) was the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of MongoSwift.

How did you install the C driver?

The crash could be coming from the first line where you are doing `try! MongoClient()`, you may want to try putting that in a try/catch as well.

Also just a note, you can  simplify your collection code to just:

```
let collection = db.collection("myCollection")
```

You only need to use `createCollection` if you want to create a collection with non-default options. Otherwise, the collection will be automatically created the first time you use it (in this case, when you add the index).